# QueryFailedError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Я использую NestJS + TypeORM и пытаюсь создать объект в базе данных Postgres, но обнаружил следующую ошибку:

QueryFailedError: нулевое значение в столбце «id» нарушает ограничение на ненулевое значение. || QueryFailedError: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

Я не могу сохранить данные в моей таблице user_analytic, в настоящее время она не содержит никаких данных, то есть пустая.

В IDE для базы данных я вижу, что напротив столбца «id» стоит галочка. Not null.

Кто сталкивался с этой трудностью и какое решение вы нашли?

> UserService

````
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { user_analytic } from 'src/entities/user-analytic-entity';
import { UserAnalyticSchema } from 'src/entities/user-analytic-schema';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class UserAnalyticService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(UserAnalyticSchema)
    private readonly _userAnalyticSchemaRepository: Repository<user_analytic>,
  ) {}
  
  
  async createNewTopTags() {
    const tags = new user_analytic()
    tags.top_tags = {
      tag1: 'Family',
    }
    await this._userAnalyticSchemaRepository.save(tags)
  }

}
> UserEntity
@Entity()
export class user_analytic extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
    id: string;

    @Column({
        type: 'json',
    })
    top_tags: object;
}



> UserSchema
import { EntitySchema } from 'typeorm';
import { user_analytic } from './user-analytic-entity';

export const UserAnalyticSchema = new EntitySchema<user_analytic>({
  name: 'users.user_analytic',
  columns: {
    id: {
      type: String,
      primary: true,
      generated: true,
    },
    top_tags: {
    type: String,
    },```
````

Comment: заменить значение type -> `type: String, primary: true` (тут) на `type: 'uuid'`?

Comment: пожалуйста переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык, или задайте его на соответствующем ресурсе

Comment: заменить значение type -> type: String, primary: true (тут) на type: 'uuid'? – 
nörbörnën

Не удается назначить параметрт `type: String`, при существующем декораторе 
`@PrimaryGeneratedColumn()`

Я также попробовал 
`@PrimaryColumn({
        type: 'uuid',
        primary: true
    })
    id: string;
`

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось в пакете uuidv4

Изменения в коде:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

   async createNewTopTags() {
    const tags = new user_analytic();
    tags.id = uuidv4();
    await tags.save();
    }
```